# How to stretch background image to container width but retain original height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a `background-image` that should repeat vertically and stretch horizontally, but keep its height as original svg.

I've tried to fix the `background-size: 100% 33px;` but the orignal height is not retained.

Height should be the same in all `.child` and it should be stretched to its parent container.

Below are my try

```
  background-size: 100% 33px;  // TO FIX SIZE
  background-repeat: repeat-y; // REPEAT ONLY THROUGH Y
```

[**CODESANDBOX LINK FOR TRY**](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-goldberg-9tss75?file=/index.html:311-442)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 5px solid indianred;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

div.child {
  background-image: url("https://assets-marvin.leadsquared.com/smartviews/images/column.svg");
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
  background-size: 100% 33px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 3;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not possiblle, either strecth it or have the original height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the SVG and add `preserveAspectRatio="none"`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  border: 5px solid indianred;
}

.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
}

div.child {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="32.5" viewBox="0 0 200 32.5" preserveAspectRatio="none"><g id="Group_15" data-name="Group 15" transform="translate(10981 1350)"><g id="Group_11" data-name="Group 11" transform="translate(-10981 -1350)"><rect id="Rectangle_43" data-name="Rectangle 43" width="200" height="31.5" fill="%23fff"/><rect id="Rectangle_44" data-name="Rectangle 44" width="176" height="20" rx="1" transform="translate(12 5.897)" fill="%23f2f2f2"/></g><line id="Line_1" data-name="Line 1" x2="200" transform="translate(-10981 -1318)" fill="none" stroke="%23ccd3da" stroke-width="1"/></g></svg>');
  background-size: 100% 33px;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 2;
}

.child:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani how did you get `data:image/svg+xml` from url?

Comment: @decpk I took the SVG, removed all the spaces to have it one line. replaced all the # with %23 and I put it inside background-image. It's a manual work